# Which Magic Ring should I choose in DungeonQuest?

Tags: dungeonquest

Which Magic Ring is superior to the others on average?

Does the best ring vary based upon which character you have?

Comment: Which version of the game? And, if it's the Games Workshop version, with the expansions or not?

Comment: @MattTrower, are the enemy distributions different? I was interested in the original, no expansion.

Comment: I don't know, but the rings are certainly different :)

Comment: In FightingFantasy's version, they're Runes instead.

Answer (score 1):

I usually try to get the Healing Ring every time I play because the Champion of Chaos and Skeleton Warrior tend to hit me pretty hard if I encounter them.